# Show warning message if user tries to bypass the startup options in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I know there is a way to disable bypassing but i don't want that ,i just want to show a warning message like "blah blah blah ...at your own risk" if the user tries to "SHIFT" his way through my db.
is that doable,thank you

Comment: I think it's not doable ...sorry for bothering